# Is the beth function continuous without the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory

Suppose the beth function is defined as follows:
beth[a]=|V[a]|, for all ordinals a. Here V[a] is the ath level of the cumulative hierarchy, and || is the cardinality function defined as in for example the Levy Basic Set Theory book.

The above definition of beth is equivalent to the usual one in the presence of the axiom of choice, and of course that beth function is known to be normal and hence continuous.

My question is whether in the absence of the axiom of choice the above beth function is continuous. Continuity here does not require the cardinalities to be ordinals but  means |V[a]| is the lub of the set of |V[b]| such that b<a, for each limit ordinal a, and according to Levy’s definition of lub of cardinalities.

The non existence of Lubs for some sets of cardinals makes me doubtful but I’m too naive to know for sure.

Comment: In the absence of choice your beth isn't a function into the ordinals so this question is a bit oddly phrased. I think it's helpful instead to rephrase it as asking whether in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone we can prove the following: for all limit ordinals $\lambda$ and all sets $A$, if $V_\alpha$ injects into $A$ for each $\alpha<\lambda$, then $V_\lambda$ injects into $A$. This statement amounts to saying that the (Scott) cardinality of a limit level of $V$ is the least upper bound of the (Scott) cardinalities of the prior levels, which I think is what you want. (And I suspect the answer is negative.)

Comment: You are correct about my use of the term normal for a function that may not be spitting out ordinals. In fact I changed my post before I saw yours. 

It’s the underlying relation   on  sets x<=y iff there is an injection from x to y that I want the lub for.  I want to know if  for limit ordinals a, |V[a]| = |UV[b]| for b<a, is known to be the lub of the |V[b]|s  is known not to be, or it is not known yet.

Comment: Since $V_\beta=\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta}V_\alpha$ for limit $\beta$ (or $\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta} V_{\alpha+1}$ if you want a general formula), it's not clear to me what you're really looking for.

Comment: It may fail already for $\alpha=\omega$: if $A$ is an infinite Dedekind finite set, then $|V_n|\le|A|$ for all $n<\omega$, but $|V_\omega|\nleq|A|$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Oh duh, I'm embarrassed I didn't see that.

Comment: What I want to know is if we don’t have the axiom of choice can we still say that given any set S with |S| > |V[a]| for all a <b, that |S| >=|V[b]|. 

What I’m asking is if we don’t have the axiom  choice is the cardinality of that beta union still the lub of the cardinalities of its lower levels (it is still an upper bound but may not be the least one).

Comment: I posted the above comment before I saw the previous one. Thanks! How about if we define least so that the the cardinality of any upper bound must be >= the least one instead of insisting that the cardinality of the lub is <= cardinality of any other upper bound. Is V[w] still not the least upper bound?

Comment: @M.Solomon how does it change the example of Emil? If there exists an infinite D-finite set then there is no least upper bound for $\{V_n\mid n\in\omega\}$

Comment: We have |V[w]| > |V[n]|  ( I.e.,no injections between those levels of the cumulative hierarchy), for all  natural numbers n and |A| > |V[w]|, so set A wouldn’t contradict |V[w]| being the lub according to my definition of lub, but something else might. Am I missing something?

Comment: If $A$ is Dedekind-finite, then $A$ does not have a countably infinite subset. In particular $V_\omega$, a countable set, does not inject into $A$. In fact, we can arrange it so that $A$ does not even surject onto $V_\omega$.

Comment: Asaf, doesn’t A not injectable to V[w] mean |A| > |V[w]| by definition, so A does not stop lub according to my definition?

Comment: @M.Solomon no, "A does not inject to B" means "$|A|\not ≤ |B|$", while $|B|<|A|$ means "B inject into A (but not surject)", it is not the same without the axiom of choice

Comment: Right. By the definition I’ve been using |A| > |S| means |A| not <= |S|, I.e., we have non injectability between those sets we are taking the cardinality. So using my definition of lub, which uses >= for the least condition instead of <= is weaker and may allow the lub we want

Comment: Asaf, the real question I have is the following. With the axiom of choice given any limit ordinal a and any set S with |S| < |V[a]|, there exists an x in V[a] with |x| =|S|. Does this hold without the axiom of choice? If so what’s a gch condition on V[a+1] becomes unconditional true on limit ordinals. My guess is that it’s false.

Comment: What I wrote still stands. Your new definition of ">" doesn't change the definition of "<". Also your "definition" is a "preorder" of the cardinals, not "partial order", so I am not even sure what do you mean by lub with your new definition...

Comment: holo, to avoid problems concerning the def of lub please see the above question I asked Asaf. That only involves = and <. = between the cardinalities of sets means there is a bijection between the sets and < means there are injections but no bijections between the sets. This  is the result I was looking for  but probably does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/438728) of Farmer S to my latest question, the answer to this question is no. Lub property on limit ordinal stages of cumulative hierarchy implies the axiom of choice. Thanks Farmer!